# Livewire v3 url parameters except alternative

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In Livewire v2 you were able to remove a url parameter using `except` if it had a certain value. I cannot find the v3 alternative of this functionality.

This is from the v2 docs:

```
    protected $queryString = [
        'foo',
        'search' => ['except' => ''],
        'page' => ['except' => 1],
    ];
```

How can I achieve this in Livewire v3?

Comment: That's a good one. Looking through the source code and it seems it's entirely impossible. They've reduced a lot of logic for it. You might need to do some override.

Comment: Have you already seen [this](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#url-query-string)?

Comment: That seems to be a solution, thanks. Although it's not as straight forward as it previously was. I'll have to fiddle with it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

with the Url attribute:
(it came out in version 3.2.0: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/releases/tag/v3.2.0)

```
use Livewire\Attributes\Url;
use Livewire\Component;
 
class ShowUsers extends Component
{
    #[Url(except: '')]
    public $search = '';
 
    public function mount() {
        $this->search = auth()->user()->username;
    }
 
    // ...
}
```